# How do I limit my query results to results that include a certain number of items in a column?

Tags: sqlite, select, group-by, count, having

I am trying to query results from my movie database that returns movies that have at least 3 actors listed. I just need to get the `titleid` and I can go from there. How do I pull the `titleid` from the table `actors` where the number of `personid`s > 3.

I have tried:

```
SELECT titleid FROM actors WHERE COUNT(personid) > 3;
```

But this appears to be a misuse of COUNT(). Is there a function I can use?

SCHEMA:

````
CREATE TABLE actors(
  titleid TEXT,
  ordering INT,
  personid TEXT,
  category TEXT,
  job TEXT,
  characters TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE actornames(
  personid TEXT,
  name TEXT,
  birth INT,
  death INT,
  profession TEXT,
  knowntitles TEXT,
  titleid TEXT,
  ordering INT,
  "personid:1" TEXT,
  category TEXT,
  job TEXT,
  characters TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE ratings (titleid TEXT, rating DEC, votes INT);

CREATE TABLE movielist(title TEXT,titleid TEXT);```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `COUNT()` aggregate function in the `HAVING` clause of an aggregation query:

```
SELECT titleid
FROM actors
GROUP BY titleid
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3;
```

Just in case an actor may be listed more than once in `actors` for the same movie, you should count the distinct `personid`s:

```
SELECT titleid
FROM actors
GROUP BY titleid
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT personid) >= 3;
```